# Weird behavior of curl and facebook

Tags: php, facebook, curl

Here is the code:

```
$ch = curl_init( 'https://graph.facebook.com/btaylor');

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, '' );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER ,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 

$data = curl_exec($ch);

print_r( $data) ;
curl_close($ch);
```

It shows few informations from facebook. It works on my localhost, but when I try to run it on my server it just doesn't work, returns a blank site. 
I tried to use this code with others sites like example.com and It works, so I thought, that its becouse of facebook blocks my ip (i dont know why it would be true), so I checked it. I have run it with

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, 'myproxy');
```

But it still doesn't show any information. I am trying to fix it all day, but its too difficult. Have you got some ideas?

Comment: Is the server a shared server or slice that could share an IP with someone else?

Comment: If there's a problem, `curl_exec()` will return false, which would display as blank with your print_r. try `if ($data === FALSE) { die("Curl error: " . curl_error()); }` after your curl_exec call. Never assume that a function call which performs network-centric actions will succeed. Always check for errors afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to guess that either curl isn't installed on your server and/or error reporting is disabled / turned down on your server.

Edit: Okay, if you know curl is installed and works, you *still* need to enable error reporting. When you *finally* see your error about "certificate verify failed," you'll need to export a X.509 Certificate (PEM) from Facebook and configure curl to trust it.

Or, if this **isn't production code**, you can just use (the **insanely insecure**):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

... to *blindly* accept Certificate Authorities.